# What is the difference between the two BOLDFACE tags and the two Italicized Tags?

Tags: html, css, tags, bold

There are two ways to make your text  BOLD.

One of them (which I personally think is an easier way):

```
</b> This is a Bold Text!</b>
```

The other one is:

`<strong> This is also a Bold text! </strong>`

So, What's the difference?  They both do the same job, so what's the point of using two tags that do the same thing? Do you think the  < strong > tag should be depreciated?

There is also two tags that can be used for *Italicised text*

The first one:

```
<i> This is Italicised </i>
```

The 2nd one:

```
 <em> This is also Italicised <em>
```

These Italicised text tags are like the bold tags, why not just keep the most efficient one?   I think we should keep the < b >  tag and the  < i > tag for our HTML documents. They are less time to consume and take up less space.

Answer (score 0):

While they both mean almost the same things, there are a few important differences:

`<b>` and `<i>` describe presentation with relation to font, while `<em>` and `<strong>` outline hierarchy, add **emphasis**, and are semantic. This means that it's easier for blind people to understand their inherent meaning.

It's also worth noting that `<em>` and `<strong>` can be targetted in CSS, where `<b>` and `<i>` cannot, so the former are preferred for modern web browsers.

Essentially, you're asking "Do I want to add **emphasis** to the delivery of my text, or do I simply want to display it in a denser font-weight?"

Hope this helps!